# Find out in what line Espresso fails exactly

Tags: automated-tests, android-espresso

I am running Espresso tests on my Android app. If one fails I the view tree is printed. Unfortunately I don't know in what line this failure occurs exactly.

Is there a way to tell Espresso to print the stack trace when an Exception is thrown (e.g. NoMatchingViewException) so I can see in what line my tests fails?

Thanks
 Thomas

EDIT:

Output I get looks like (removed part in the middle):

```
android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'with id: com.wombatl.mobility.charge.test:id/stopChargingButton' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
Problem views are marked with '****MATCHES****' below.
View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=2160, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) ty=1 fl=#81810100 pfl=0x20000 wanim=0x10302f6 needsMenuKey=2 colorMode=0}, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
|
+->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=2034, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@48dbdb, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|

(...)

|
+--------------->AppCompatTextView{id=2131361990, res-name=hoursTextView, visibility=VISIBLE, width=68, height=53, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.Rela
```

Comment: Please provide the error log.

Comment: Added log to post as EDIT

Comment: Mhm. Now I see that it's somehow cut-off. Wonder why Espresso does not write it completely.

Comment: Now that is the question you should ask instead.

Comment: This issue is very annoying.

Comment: It is possible that this error could be caused by a custom view attached to the activity - which has multiple instances on the screen. Checking if the custom view is having multiple instances in the parent view could fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

No, the line number will not be shown in the failure message. You will have to deduce it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

It is clearly stated that you have multiple matches for the view with id `stopChargingButton`. That's it.

```
android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'with id: com.wombatl.mobility.charge.test:id/stopChargingButton' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
```

View matchers should match only one element otherwise Espresso doesn't know what view to operate on and throws the exception. Add additional matching criteria to identify specific view on the screen. You may use `allOf()` hamcrest matcher for this purpose.

If the view you wanna operate on is the part of the `ListView` - use `onData()`. If it is inside `RecyclerView` look in the documentation how to operate on the item which is the part of the `RecyclerView`.